# Case Create Workflow Fails with SLA : PopulateBusinessClosureRequests Failed

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a workflow that creates cases from emails. I also have a simple SLA that is associated to the cases.

Recently I have noticed a large number of the case creation jobs failing with an error like this:

```
Plugin Trace:

[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.CreateEntity]
[CreateStep6]

    [Microsoft.Crm.Service.ObjectModel: Microsoft.Crm.Service.ObjectModel.CasePostCreatePlugin]
    [ffde44b1-a685-4948-85b8-e4091bc2a98b: CasePostCreatePlugin]


        [Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin]
        [46f6cf4c-14ae-4f1e-98a1-eae99a37e95c: ExecuteWorkflowWithInputArguments]
        Starting sync workflow 'Case Follow Up', Id: b5983018-1027-e611-80bb-0050568f6e8c
        Entering ConditionStep1_step: Case Follow Up
        Entering ConditionStep5_step: Check condition step - Applicable When- KPI1
        Entering ConditionStep7_step:
        Entering ConditionStep9_step:
        Sync workflow 'Case Follow Up' terminated with error 'PopulateBusinessClosureRequests Failed'



Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: PopulateBusinessClosureRequests Failed
```

We do have working hours that is linked to a holiday schedule.

I cant seem to find a cause for the "PopulateBusinessClosureRequests" failure.

This is CRM 2016 U0.1 on-prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We raised the issue with Microsoft, and it turns out that there is an issue in the product. 
At the time of this answer they were working on a fix to be included in a service pack.